# No se almacenan los datos en la base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdo

hola querría ver si alguna persona amable seria capaz de corregir mi código y ayudarme a entender que esta mal con el, llevo varios días intentando hacer una pagina de registro con PHP y MySQL y cuando quiero implementar el campo de que si el email ya esta registrado de una aviso, se me rompe todo y ya nada funciona,he cambiado la base de datos varias veces pero cuanto mas lo toco mas lo estropeo, en fin este es mi código y acto seguido el comando que use para crear la base de datos en PhpmyAdmin(se me olvido comentar que cuando ya hay un usuario guardado en la base de datos no se guardan mas y salta el error de que el usuario esta duplicado cuanto intentas insertar mas,muchas gracias de antemano)

```
<?php

try {
    $server="localhost:3306";
    $username='root';
    $passworddb="";
    $database="php_login_database";
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username, $passworddb);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];


    $query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`) VALUES (:email, :password)";
    $statement = $link->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':email' =>$email,
        ':password' => $password,
    ));
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
        if ($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
           echo"email o nickname duplicado";
        } else {
           echo"algo salio mal, intentelo mas tarde";
        }
     }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        
        <title>Register V5.0</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

        <meta name="description" content="A description.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <?php include "partials/header.php"?>

        <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
            <p> <?= $message ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <h1>crear cuenta</h1>


        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="email">
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="contraseña">
            <input name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña">
            <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit">

        <span><br>o <a href="login.php">logueate</a></span>
    </body>
</html>


    CREATE TABLE users (
        id int NOT NULL,
        email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        password varchar(255),
        UNIQUE (id,email)
    
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema era que no le estaba dando valor al id y lo tenia en UNIQUE asi que siempre era 0 y por eso no lo añadia